# removing padding from default ActionBar TabView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, tabview

I have custom layout for each tab on actionbar tabview. Problem is that the background is not taking the whole space allocated for tab.. it looks like padding is applied on background. Any help with it?

My custom layout for tab is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/icon">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/info" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Info"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

this gives following: 
[image]

Comment: upload snapshot of your output.

Comment: use match_parent instead of wrap_context.

Comment: i was talking about background of linearlayout .. not the children

Comment: you have to upload the full screen-shot.Because this code seems fine.